# SharePoint Workflow doesn't work. (Call HTTP Web Service) Sie haben diesen Thread abonniert. System.ApplicationException HTTP 500

Tags: workflow, workflow-manager, web, https

I have following problem with my workflow:

The workflow should get every entry from the list which has the same user as the actual column.

But when I publish the workflow suspends and I get the error message "HTTP 500".

For the dictionary I use:

```
Accept

Content-Type

(application/json;odata=verbose)
```

Here are some Screenshots:

[image: Workflow definition image]

[image: Workflow error image]

[image]

[image]

[image: When I log the Service-URL to the WF]

Comment: Can you provide more details (screenshot?) on the request header and body content, HTTP 500 indicates that the problem lies in one of those. The details you provided about the dictionary are not clear is that two dictionary entries in the form of: Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply. I added 2 new screenshots for the Problem. Thanks for your help! The dictionary is added correct to the RequestHeaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem!
The reason was the "log Results:".
After i deleted this line it worked fine.

Thanks for your help!

BR
Manuel

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is in the web service call URL, can you test that directly in the browser?

Looking at a custom list in SharePoint here I can see that the custom columns of the User type (People Picker) fields show as "UserId" only and not as an expandable field as you have it in your query string, so perhaps your URL should look like:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list name')/items?$select=[select fields]&$filter=UserId eq '[id]'
```

Either way if you test your url with a valid SP User ID in any browser you should get the expected response.

Finally you can also check the variables you are passing, ensure that [%Current Item:User%] is definitely just the SP User Id (e.g. an int like 10).

Hope that helps,
Martin

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my call URL works fine in the browser but not in the workflow. The query is: "site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('name')/items?$select=Inventory_x0020_Number,Hostname,Model,Manufacturer&$expand=User&$select=User/ID&$filter=User/Id eq [%Current Item:User%]" And the current Item User is set to the ID.

Comment: If I don't use the $expand=User i get an "BadRequest-Error" in the ResponseCode...

Comment: The list is very big. (1898 entrys). Could this be another reason?

Comment: That's easy to test with a ?$top=1000 or something, however the default list view threshold is 5000.

Comment: Hi, for the comment about the $expand, if you're still getting errors, add some logging to the workflow to log the variables and such, you might find some variable has a strange value resulting in the error 500.

Comment: Hi, when i log the Service-URL in the workflow then I get an link which works, but "eq [%Current Item:User%]" is not an link, just a normal text. I added a screenshot to the question.